# xcodeproj how do I get my original file open again

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I had the normal file open running everything fine, in Xcode, and I closed it. When I opened it up again it was on the .xcodeproj file and I couldn't select the type of phone the program was to be run on, now it's on "any iOS device (arm64)" I tried a bunch of different things to get back into the full program file that I originally had going but I wouldn't be writing on here looking for help if any worked. I'd appreciate it if anyone knows what to do and they wouldn't mind helping me out.

Comment: Open the Devices And Simulators window. Switch to Simulators. Are there any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the "any iOS device (arm64)"

[image]

You should see a list of iOS simulators, that you can select to run your app. if you don't see a list of simulators. then click *Add Additional Simulators*

[image]

you should then be able to add additional simulators by clicking the *"+"* button at the bottom shown in the image below.

[image]

You can then just create any simulator you require.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Wantopinions If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept the answer for further references.